# How can I show a count of rows from an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have a table on my web page that is populated with data like this:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data | filter:isQuestionInRange">
   <td>{{ row.problemId }}</td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way that I can put a count of the rows displayed in the table footer. Note that I want to be able to show the rows after that have been filtered not just the row count from the grid.data array.

Comment: You mean showing this: '{{(grid.data | filter:isQuestionInRange).length}}'?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could check the length of the filtered array such as:

```
{{ (grid.data | filter:isQuestionInRange).length }}
```

Comment: I am trying to create a dynamic html table with json response which i will get from a web api, so i don't know number of columns and column names. In that case what to write <td>{{ here }}</td> ?? Thanks

Answer (score 22):

You can store the results of the filter and then get the length of that, for example using `results` here:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="row in results = (grid.data | filter:isQuestionInRange)">
   <td>{{ row.problemID }}</td>
</tr>
{{results.length}}
```

This has the performance advantage of only needing to run the filter once.  It's also handy for other situations where you need both filtered and unfiltered results within your `ng-repeat`.

Comment: nice answer... `results.length` is also a lot clearer to read than `(grid.data | filter:isQuestionInRange).length`

Comment: Note that this sets a property results on the current scope. If there are other directives that create scopes above the point where the property is referenced then it might not be available see http://plnkr.co/edit/PGQ2DLI33jF43BLricUO?p=preview

Comment: I am trying to create a dynamic html table with json response which i will get from a web api, so i don't know number of columns and column names. In that case what to write <td>{{ here }}</td> ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the [$filter service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24filter) in your controller, like shown in [this example plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/nKoOnTTl25GOLL3mKCC0?p=preview):

```
$scope.evenNumbers = $filter('filter')($scope.numbers, $scope.isEven);
```

In your case:

```
var $scope.filteredRows = $filter('filter')($scope.gridData, $scope.isQuestionInRange);
```

This way you do the filtering only once and avoid to introduce new scope fields in the template which makes your code hard to test and to understand.

You repeat over `filteredRows` in your template and `{{ filteredRows.length }}` gives you the number of visible rows.