# How can I watch the number of elements in a filtered ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following ng-repeat?

```
<table>
<tr data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data | filter:isProblemInRange>
<td>xxx</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The rows are filtered with isProblemInRange function which is based on the value of two input fields. Depending on what I put in these fields the number of rows displayed can change.

Is it possible for me to do a watch on the number of rows that are present on the screen and if so how can I do this from inside my controller?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19956685/340128

The defined variable `results` is appended to the scope and can be accessed from the controller as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [$filter service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24filter) in your controller:

```
var $scope.filteredRows = $filter('filter')($scope.gridData, $scope.isProblemInRange);
```

and run the ng-repeat over the filtered rows. This way you avoid to introduce new scope fields in the template which makes your code hard to test and to maintain.

See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/nKoOnTTl25GOLL3mKCC0?p=preview) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $scope.filteredRows = $filter('filter')($scope.gridData, $scope.isProblemInRange);

$scope.$watch('filteredRows',function(newVal,oldVal){
    if(!angular.equals(newVal.length,oldVal.length)){
        [... Do stuff here when the number of filtered rows changes ...]
    }
});

$scope.$watch('gridData',function(newVal,oldVal){
    if(!angular.equals(newVal,oldVal)){
        $scope.filteredRows = $filter('filter')($scope.gridData, $scope.isProblemInRange);
    }
});
```